# How To Get Value In Rest API HTML Response

Tags: rest

How can I get the value your_data:ko2bop447a3 in the response from Rest Request API? I get the HTML as the reply.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>
<body>                                                                                                               <ul id="mastmenu" class="primary-menu clearfix"><li id="menu-item-1149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-1149"><a href="https://www.example.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1200"><a href="https://www.example.com/services-2/">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1129"><a href="#">Who We Are<span class="main-menu-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1144"><a href="https://www.example.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1153"><a href="https://www.example.com/our-team/">Our Team</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1159"><a href="https://www.example.com/careers/">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var adc_ajax = {"ajaxurl":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/opi\/hjj-ajax.php","your_data":"ko2bop447a3"};
/* ]]> */


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention which language using it.
I can provide three different way to get the key's value.
Using node.js, python and Postman.

##### This is demo for REST API server by node.js

Save as server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Define the HTML data as a string
const htmlData = `
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="mastmenu" class="primary-menu clearfix">
        <li id="menu-item-1149"
            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-1149"><a
                href="https://www.example.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1200"><a
                href="https://www.example.com/services-2/">Services</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1129"
            class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1129"><a
                href="#">Who We Are<span class="main-menu-toggle"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1144">
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1153">
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/our-team/">Our Team</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1159">
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/careers/">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        /*
        <![CDATA[ */
var adc_ajax = {"ajaxurl":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/opi\/hjj-ajax.php","your_data":"ko2bop447a3"};
/* ]]> */
</body>
</html>
`;

// Define a route to handle GET requests to "/data"
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  // Set the response content type to HTML
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  
  // Send the HTML data as the response
  res.send(htmlData);
});

// Start the Express server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

##### Install dependencies (server.js and client.js)

```bash
npm install express axios
```

##### Run server

```bash
node server.js
```

##### Client by node.js

save as `cleint.js`

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/data'; // Replace with your server URL

const keyName = 'your_data'; // Replace with the desired variable name

// Make a GET request using Axios
axios.get(serverUrl)
  .then(response => {
    const htmlData = response.data;
    const variablePattern = `"${keyName}":"`;
    const startIndex = htmlData.indexOf(variablePattern);
    
    if (startIndex !== -1) {
      const endIndex = htmlData.indexOf('"', startIndex + variablePattern.length);
      if (endIndex !== -1) {
        const variableValue = htmlData.substring(startIndex + variablePattern.length, endIndex);
        console.log(`Extracted ${keyName}:`, variableValue);
      } else {
        console.log(`"${keyName}" value not found in HTML`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`"${keyName}" not found in HTML`);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

##### Run it

```bash
node client.js
```

Result

```
> node client.js
Extracted your_data: ko2bop447a3
```

[image]

##### Client by python

save as `cleint.py`

```py
import requests
import re

server_url = 'http://localhost:3000/data'  # Replace with your server URL

keyName = 'your_data'  # Replace with the desired variable name

try:
    # Make a GET request using requests
    response = requests.get(server_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Extract the variable value from the response HTML
        html_data = response.text
        variable_pattern = f'"{keyName}":"(.*?)"'
        match = re.search(variable_pattern, html_data)

        if match:
            variable_value = match.group(1)
            print(f'Extracted {keyName}: {variable_value}')
        else:
            print(f'"{keyName}" value not found in HTML')
    else:
        print(f'Error: Status code {response.status_code}')
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f'Error: {e}')
```

##### Run it

```bash
python client.py
```

Result

```
>python client.py
Extracted your_data: ko2bop447a3
```

[image]

##### Client by Postman

URL

```
GET http://localhost:3000/data
```

**Tests** Tab

```js
// Get the response body as a string
var responseBody = pm.response.text();

// Define the variable name you want to extract
var keyName= 'your_data';

// Define a regular expression pattern to match the variable and its value
var pattern = `"${keyName}":"(.*?)"`;

// Use regular expression to extract the value
var matches = responseBody.match(new RegExp(pattern));

if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
    var variableValue = matches[1];
    console.log(`Extracted ${keyName}: ${variableValue}`);
} else {
    console.log(`"${keyName}" value not found in response`);
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I didn't mention the language but it was python I was working with. And you have given me what I needed, THANK YOU.

Comment: No problem, happy to code!